# How to read a text file without a specific directory?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that needs to read data from a text file.

Right now, to open the text file I use

```
File readFile = new File("src/txtFile.txt")
```

I want it to not be specific so that when I send it to someone and they decide to place my jar and txt file inside a folder like their Downloads folder with "program/App.jar and txtFile.txt" the program can still find it within the folder the user placed it in.

Comment: Did `("./txtFile.txt")` not work?

Comment: If you dont want to be specific, let the user pass the path as argument

Comment: ("./txtFile.txt") doesn't work. It says "Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\txtFile.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)"

Comment: @Miles it's a bit hard to have both (i.e.: it works when you launch it from your IDE and it works when you launch it from the jar) without writing the appropriate code to handle both cases. You could try and read from `./` and, if it throws that `FileNotFoundException` you can try from `src/` so that both cases are accounted for. But better yet, as XtremeBaumer suggests, ask the user to provide the path to the file.

Comment: Try calling `new File('.").getAbsolutePath()` and show it somewhere in order to know what Java is considering to be the "base" directory in each instance. This will help you understand why it isn't finding the file.

Comment: Replace `File readFile = new File("src/txtFile.txt")` with `File readFile = new File("txtFile.txt").getAbsoluteFile()`. Then the error message will tell you exactly where the program was looking for the file. You should then be able to figure out how to `cd` to the correct directory where txtFile.txt exists, and run it from there.

Answer (score 3):

You need to take the file path as an argument from your `main()` function (see [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)) and create your `File` instance from it.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
        final String filePath = args[0];
        File readFile = new File(filePath);
    }
}
```

then the argument can be passed while running the jar directly

```
java --jar path/to/myprog.jar path/to/myfile.txt
```

or by specifying it in a launch configuration in your IDE.

Comment: There are other ways to pass info from user to program such as Java properties on environment variable.